# Get Text From Row

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I stuck at point where I'm unable to get the text of the items. I'm able to get the web-elements from the xpath defined, but when the FOR loop is executed it returns all the values from the 1st row in every iteration. Below is the code written for the same.

```
Extract Rows With Shipment No And Latest Updated On Date
    [Arguments]    ${shipment_no}
    ${rows}=    RPA.Browser.Selenium.Get WebElements    xpath=//button[contains(text(),'${shipment_no}')]/ancestor::tr
    ${filtered_rows}=    Create List
    FOR    ${row}    IN    @{rows}
        ${shipment_no}=    RPA.Browser.Selenium.Get Text    xpath=(.//td[contains(.,'${shipment_no}')])
        ${updated_on}=    RPA.Browser.Selenium.Get Text    xpath=.//td[6]  
        ${current_status}=    RPA.Browser.Selenium.Get Text    xpath=.//td[5]
        ${form_code}=    RPA.Browser.Selenium.Get Text    xpath=.//td[3]
        ${row_data}    Create Dictionary
        Set To Dictionary    ${row_data}    shipment=${shipment_no}    updated_on=${updated_on}    status=${current_status}    form_code=${form_code}
        Append To List    ${filtered_rows}    ${row_data}
    END
```

I've tried changing the xpath's but nothing worked out. I also, tried getting first the count of the rows with the required shipment_no and then pass that in the xpath for getting the texts.

What I used so far:

1. xpath=${row}/td[6] --> not a valid xpath expression
2. xpath=(//button[contains(text(),'${shipment_no}')]/ancestor::tr)//td[6]
3. xpath=(//button[contains(text(),'${shipment_no}')]/ancestor::tr[${index}])//td[6] - when tried with count instead of web-elements

The requirement is to get the shipment_no, current_status, form_code based on updated_date.

Sample HTML:

```
<table class="MuiTable-root customize-mui-table  css-fyul2s">
  <thead class="MuiTableHead-root css-1wbz3t9">
    <tr class="MuiTableRow-root MuiTableRow-head css-1ig0b5l">
      <th class="MuiTableCell-root MuiTableCell-head MuiTableCell-paddingCheckbox MuiTableCell-sizeSmall css-145xgxe" scope="col">
        <span class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiCheckbox-root MuiCheckbox-colorPrimary MuiCheckbox-sizeMedium PrivateSwitchBase-root MuiCheckbox-root MuiCheckbox-colorPrimary MuiCheckbox-sizeMedium MuiCheckbox-root MuiCheckbox-colorPrimary MuiCheckbox-sizeMedium css-hx4djs">
          <input class="PrivateSwitchBase-input css-1m9pwf3" type="checkbox" data-indeterminate="false">
      <th class="MuiTableCell-root MuiTableCell-head MuiTableCell-sizeSmall css-ven4fa" scope="col" style="cursor: pointer;">
        <span class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiTableSortLabel-root css-24fsnk" tabindex="0" role="button">Shipment No.</span>
      </th>
      <th class="MuiTableCell-root MuiTableCell-head MuiTableCell-sizeSmall css-ven4fa" scope="col" style="cursor: pointer;">
        <span class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiTableSortLabel-root css-24fsnk" tabindex="0" role="button">BCG Code</span>
      </th>
      <th class="MuiTableCell-root MuiTableCell-head MuiTableCell-sizeSmall css-ven4fa" scope="col" style="cursor: pointer;">
        <span class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiTableSortLabel-root css-24fsnk" tabindex="0" role="button">Application No.</span>
      </th>
      <th class="MuiTableCell-root MuiTableCell-head MuiTableCell-sizeSmall css-ven4fa" scope="col" style="cursor: pointer;">
        <span class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiTableSortLabel-root css-24fsnk" tabindex="0" role="button">Status</span>
      </th>
      <th class="MuiTableCell-root MuiTableCell-head MuiTableCell-sizeSmall css-ven4fa" scope="col" style="cursor: pointer;">
        <span class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiTableSortLabel-root css-24fsnk" tabindex="0" role="button">Updated On</span>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="MuiTableBody-root css-1xnox0e">
    <tr class="MuiTableRow-root MuiTableRow-hover css-1ig0b5l">
      <td class="MuiTableCell-root MuiTableCell-body MuiTableCell-paddingCheckbox MuiTableCell-sizeSmall css-1k6g83o">
        <span class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiCheckbox-root MuiCheckbox-colorPrimary MuiCheckbox-sizeMedium PrivateSwitchBase-root MuiCheckbox-root MuiCheckbox-colorPrimary MuiCheckbox-sizeMedium MuiCheckbox-root MuiCheckbox-colorPrimary MuiCheckbox-sizeMedium css-wumm0i">
          <input class="PrivateSwitchBase-input css-1m9pwf3" type="checkbox" data-indeterminate="false">
          <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root css-w0pj6f"></span>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td class="MuiTableCell-root MuiTableCell-body MuiTableCell-sizeSmall css-g6r8ja">
        <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiButton-root MuiButton-text MuiButton-textPrimary MuiButton-sizeMedium MuiButton-textSizeMedium MuiButton-root MuiButton-text MuiButton-textPrimary MuiButton-sizeMedium MuiButton-textSizeMedium listing-btn css-ribjru" tabindex="0" type="button">245148 - IND<span class="MuiTouchRipple-root css-w0pj6f"></span>
        </button>
      </td>
      <td class="MuiTableCell-root MuiTableCell-body MuiTableCell-sizeSmall css-g6r8ja">BCG-21</td>
      <td class="MuiTableCell-root MuiTableCell-body MuiTableCell-sizeSmall css-g6r8ja">14945343</td>
      <td class="MuiTableCell-root MuiTableCell-body MuiTableCell-sizeSmall css-g6r8ja">Pending for shipment</td>
      <td class="MuiTableCell-root MuiTableCell-body MuiTableCell-sizeSmall css-g6r8ja">02-17-2024</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="MuiTableRow-root MuiTableRow-hover css-1ig0b5l">
      <td class="MuiTableCell-root MuiTableCell-body MuiTableCell-paddingCheckbox MuiTableCell-sizeSmall css-1k6g83o">
        <span class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiCheckbox-root MuiCheckbox-colorPrimary MuiCheckbox-sizeMedium PrivateSwitchBase-root MuiCheckbox-root MuiCheckbox-colorPrimary MuiCheckbox-sizeMedium MuiCheckbox-root MuiCheckbox-colorPrimary MuiCheckbox-sizeMedium css-wumm0i">
          <input class="PrivateSwitchBase-input css-1m9pwf3" type="checkbox" data-indeterminate="false">
          <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root css-w0pj6f"></span>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td class="MuiTableCell-root MuiTableCell-body MuiTableCell-sizeSmall css-g6r8ja">
        <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiButton-root MuiButton-text MuiButton-textPrimary MuiButton-sizeMedium MuiButton-textSizeMedium MuiButton-root MuiButton-text MuiButton-textPrimary MuiButton-sizeMedium MuiButton-textSizeMedium listing-btn css-ribjru" tabindex="0" type="button">245148 - IND<span class="MuiTouchRipple-root css-w0pj6f"></span>
        </button>
      </td>
      <td class="MuiTableCell-root MuiTableCell-body MuiTableCell-sizeSmall css-g6r8ja">BCG-15</td>
      <td class="MuiTableCell-root MuiTableCell-body MuiTableCell-sizeSmall css-g6r8ja">14945343</td>
      <td class="MuiTableCell-root MuiTableCell-body MuiTableCell-sizeSmall css-g6r8ja">Pending for shipment</td>
      <td class="MuiTableCell-root MuiTableCell-body MuiTableCell-sizeSmall css-g6r8ja">02-17-2024</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="MuiTableRow-root MuiTableRow-hover css-1ig0b5l">
      <td class="MuiTableCell-root MuiTableCell-body MuiTableCell-paddingCheckbox MuiTableCell-sizeSmall css-1k6g83o">
        <span class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiCheckbox-root MuiCheckbox-colorPrimary MuiCheckbox-sizeMedium PrivateSwitchBase-root MuiCheckbox-root MuiCheckbox-colorPrimary MuiCheckbox-sizeMedium MuiCheckbox-root MuiCheckbox-colorPrimary MuiCheckbox-sizeMedium css-wumm0i">
          <input class="PrivateSwitchBase-input css-1m9pwf3" type="checkbox" data-indeterminate="false">
          <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root css-w0pj6f"></span>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td class="MuiTableCell-root MuiTableCell-body MuiTableCell-sizeSmall css-g6r8ja">
        <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiButton-root MuiButton-text MuiButton-textPrimary MuiButton-sizeMedium MuiButton-textSizeMedium MuiButton-root MuiButton-text MuiButton-textPrimary MuiButton-sizeMedium MuiButton-textSizeMedium listing-btn css-ribjru" tabindex="0" type="button">10336 - IND<span class="MuiTouchRipple-root css-w0pj6f"></span>
        </button>
      </td>
      <td class="MuiTableCell-root MuiTableCell-body MuiTableCell-sizeSmall css-g6r8ja">BCG-21</td>
      <td class="MuiTableCell-root MuiTableCell-body MuiTableCell-sizeSmall css-g6r8ja">15119831</td>
      <td class="MuiTableCell-root MuiTableCell-body MuiTableCell-sizeSmall css-g6r8ja">Pending for shipment</td>
      <td class="MuiTableCell-root MuiTableCell-body MuiTableCell-sizeSmall css-g6r8ja">02-16-2024</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="MuiTableRow-root MuiTableRow-hover css-1ig0b5l">
      <td class="MuiTableCell-root MuiTableCell-body MuiTableCell-paddingCheckbox MuiTableCell-sizeSmall css-1k6g83o">
        <span class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiCheckbox-root MuiCheckbox-colorPrimary MuiCheckbox-sizeMedium PrivateSwitchBase-root MuiCheckbox-root MuiCheckbox-colorPrimary MuiCheckbox-sizeMedium MuiCheckbox-root MuiCheckbox-colorPrimary MuiCheckbox-sizeMedium css-wumm0i">
          <input class="PrivateSwitchBase-input css-1m9pwf3" type="checkbox" data-indeterminate="false">
          <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root css-w0pj6f"></span>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td class="MuiTableCell-root MuiTableCell-body MuiTableCell-sizeSmall css-g6r8ja">
        <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiButton-root MuiButton-text MuiButton-textPrimary MuiButton-sizeMedium MuiButton-textSizeMedium MuiButton-root MuiButton-text MuiButton-textPrimary MuiButton-sizeMedium MuiButton-textSizeMedium listing-btn css-ribjru" tabindex="0" type="button">245150 - IND<span class="MuiTouchRipple-root css-w0pj6f"></span>
        </button>
      </td>
      <td class="MuiTableCell-root MuiTableCell-body MuiTableCell-sizeSmall css-g6r8ja">BCG-1390</td>
      <td class="MuiTableCell-root MuiTableCell-body MuiTableCell-sizeSmall css-g6r8ja">14991470</td>
      <td class="MuiTableCell-root MuiTableCell-body MuiTableCell-sizeSmall css-g6r8ja">Shipment Completed</td>
      <td class="MuiTableCell-root MuiTableCell-body MuiTableCell-sizeSmall css-g6r8ja">02-16-2024</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="MuiTableRow-root MuiTableRow-hover css-1ig0b5l">
      <td class="MuiTableCell-root MuiTableCell-body MuiTableCell-paddingCheckbox MuiTableCell-sizeSmall css-1k6g83o">
        <span class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiCheckbox-root MuiCheckbox-colorPrimary MuiCheckbox-sizeMedium PrivateSwitchBase-root MuiCheckbox-root MuiCheckbox-colorPrimary MuiCheckbox-sizeMedium MuiCheckbox-root MuiCheckbox-colorPrimary MuiCheckbox-sizeMedium css-wumm0i">
  </tbody>
</table>
```